# MFC CFileDialog open at location that was selected by user at last run

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, registry, cfiledialog

I have an MFC C++ application, which has a CFileDialog.
I call its DoModal function to open a file browse window.
I set the lpstrInitialDir, to tell it where to open the dialog at the first time

```
CString defaultDir = L"C:\\tmp\\";
CFileDialog d(TRUE);
d.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = defaultDir ;

if( d.DoModal ()==IDOK )
    {... app logic after the file was seslected...}
```

The problem is I would like my program to remember the user selection. Next time the user runs my app, I would like my DoModal filebrowse dialog to open at the location, from which the user selected the file at his last use.

How can I do it?

I saw there is LastVisitedMRU Registry key, nut I couldn't find any example how to properly use it with the CFileDialog.DoModal

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won’t need to use “LastVisitedMRU” to accomplish this.  Simply use the [CWinApp::GetProfileString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62txabd8.aspx) and [CWinApp::WriteProfileString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t453x0d8.aspx) methods to read and write the path of the last accessed file.  For example…

```
CString defaultDir = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileString(_T(“<registry key>"), _T("LastPath"));

CFileDialog d(TRUE);
d.m_ofn.lpstrInitialDir = defaultDir;
CString selectedPath = _T("");
BOOL rc = FALSE;

if (d.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
    selectedPath = d.GetPathName();
    rc = AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString(_T("<registry key>"), _T("LastPath"), selectedPath);
    }
```

Where, "*registry key*" is the value you used in the *SetRegistry* key call in your application's InitInstance method (if it’s not there, add it).  And, "*LastPath*" is whatever you want for the registry sub-key.

*NOTE:  The sample code is from an MBCS project.*